# no login screen after 12.10 ubuntu update

Tags: 12.10, networking, gnome, lightdm, desktop-environments

i am running dual boot os machine including windows7 and ubuntu.
few days back, i did update to 12.10 version, and at that time i was using gnome fallback desktop environment.

while doing update, i could see in remove obsolete packages, it removed some gnome related files. and at that time i was using gnome fall-back desktop environment with clear looks theme, because i did not like unity much.

when i restarted machine, it gave me option to select Ubuntu / windows7, when i selected ubuntu, it showed me ubuntu logo, but from that point, only black screen would remain there, and no login screen would come, no matter how far i waited.

using advance options in menu (and askubuntu/ubuntu forums) i tried following methods, but to no avail.

1. booting to old kernel 3.5 and 2.6/2.4.
2. `dpkg-reconfigure gdm`(and both lightdm), setting it to lightdm. 
    and restarting lightdm
3. `sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu-2d` (no use)
4. `chown username:username .Xauthority` (its already on my username)
5. `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` to say `/usr/sbin/lightdm` (it was
   already there)

and one more doubt:

some solutions suggest to install and reinstall packages, for e.g

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

how do i install packages even after enabling networking, if i need a manual login, on web page provided by my ISP for starting internet connection.

machine: 32bit, intel pentium 4CPU 3.2 Ghz, Standard VGA Graphics Adapter, 1GB RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying above methods and various online suggestions, (which failed, in my case), I formatted / (root) drive by installing fresh 12.04 LTS edition. This didn't deleted my /home and other data, and nothing was lost except few installed programs (which i installed later on).