# Installing Desktop Environment, (machine offline)

Tags: 13.10, gui, desktop-environments

I tried updating my machine, to Ubuntu 13.10.
After update, when I restarted my machine, there was no GUI (no login screen), but I could access terminal, and see my files and folders.
Tried various online advice, but to no avail.
It looks like its only Desktop Environment problem. Can I install any (light weight) desktop environment, via offline method. Like, downloading some files, and putting them in right directories.

Same problem occurred during 12.10 update. About which you can read at:

[no login screen after 12.10 ubuntu update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319093/no-login-screen-after-12-10-ubuntu-update/321057#321057)

Desktop machine config :  32bit, intel pentium 4CPU 3.2 Ghz, Standard VGA Graphics Adapter, 1GB RAM

Thanks, for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Those versions are discontinued and not supported.

You must edit the file and change /etc/apt/sources.list repositories.

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo su
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Delete the contents of the file and paste this:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted
```

Control + O, save file. Control + X, close nano.

Then run the following command:

```
sudo su
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

And enjoy it.

Note: You can install new applications, such as Apache OpenOffice, Mozilla Firefox, Thunderbird, Master PDF Editor, downloading the packages from their sites:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz/download

https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-32.0.1-SSL&os=linux&lang=en-US

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/download/?product=thunderbird-31.1.1&os=linux&lang=en-US

http://code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor_1.9.25_i386.deb

Comment: While using sudo command, I encountered Login incorrect message.
Tried resetting password, which got reset but still Login incorrect message problem.
Password reset link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Answer (score 0):

As ubuntu 13.x is no longer supported, my suggestion if you are not one to be willing to really get deep in your system editing critical files is to simply use another computer to burn a 14.04 disk, and do a fresh install without formatting the installation there. It will preserve all of your user files so long as you create an account with the same username and password.